# Horizontal line below figure

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I would to have a horizontal line below my figure caption. To this end, I used the following:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}
```

Then I obtain the following figure:[image]

I only want the horizontal line below 'Figure 3.4', and not below my subcaption (a) and (b).

How do I remove the 2 horizontal lines under the subcaption?

Comment: Remove that \hrulefillfrom the caption definition and place it just before the \end{figure}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an explicit format for the `subcaption`s that doesn't use `myformat`, but `default` instead:

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=default}
```